Transaction signature verification failure - @solana/web3.js
I have a small problem. I have a ready v0 transaction that was signed by a remote wallet. I need to sign this transaction as well, which I am doing:
tx.sign([keyPair]);

Then, when the transaction is ready to be sent and signed, I get the actual block hash using RPC and send the transaction:
const { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash('confirmed');
console.log('>>> BLOCKHASH', blockhash);
tx.message.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
const txId = await connection.sendTransaction(tx, {
   skipPreflight: false,
   maxRetries: 5
});

After trying to send the transaction I get an error Transaction signature verification failure, if I don't put the actual blockchain, the transaction will not pass accordingly, and I assume this error occurs because of it. I have another blockchain which has already been set by the remote wallet in this transaction and signed, but it is not actual and I get an error that the blockchain is not found.
I tried sending transactions with different blockchains or alternately, but they all failed
